# "FATAL: Module not found error" using modprobe

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a problem with `modprobe` command... I compiled the hello world module and loaded it with `insmod`, it works fine and when I do `lsmod`, I can see it in the output list. But when I insert this module using `modprobe` I am getting a FATAL error:

```
root@okapi:/home/ravi# modprobe ./hello.ko 
FATAL: Module ./hello.ko not found.
root@okapi:/home/ravi#
```

Here is the module code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
        return 0;
}
static void hello_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

and Makefile

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason is that `modprobe` looks into `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` for the modules and therefore won't work with local file path. That's one of differences between `modprobe` and `insmod`.

Comment: so if i put my module in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` directory then will it work??

Comment: @Ravi Gupta: That would be my best guess.

Comment: try putting it in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/

Comment: @RaviGupta, the kernel Makefile that you invoke to build your module, also has other targets, such as `modules_install` that you can use to install your module.

Comment: First do `sudo depmod` to re-generate the module dependencies, than `modprobe your_module`.

Answer (score 7):

The best thing is to actually use the kernel makefile to install the module:

Here is are snippets to add to your Makefile

*around the top add:*

```
PWD=$(shell pwd)
VER=$(shell uname -r)
KERNEL_BUILD=/lib/modules/$(VER)/build
# Later if you want to package the module binary you can provide an INSTALL_ROOT
# INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/install-root
```

*around the end add:*

```
install:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_BUILD) M=$(PWD) \
           INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(INSTALL_ROOT) modules_install
```

and then you can issue

```
    sudo make install
```

this will put it either in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/

or /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/

and run depmod appropriately

Answer (score 3):

i think there should be entry of your your_module.ko in /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.dep and in /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.dep.bin for "modprobe your_module" command to work

Comment: (in other words: run `sudo depmod -a`)

Comment: @Ash great tip.

Answer (score 2):

Try `insmod` instead of modprobe. Modprobe
looks in the module directory /lib/modules/`uname -r` for all the modules and other
files

Comment: Yeah but the options are different... how would one then do `modprobe -r -q <module>`?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your network is brought down before loading module:

```
sudo stop networking
```

It helped me - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

Answer (score -1):

```
Insert this in your Makefile

 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install                      

 it will install the module in the directory /lib/modules/<var>/extra/
 After make , insert module with modprobe module_name (without .ko extension)
```

OR

```
After your normal make, you copy module module_name.ko into   directory  /lib/modules/<var>/extra/
```

then do modprobe module_name (without .ko extension)