# VMware tools installation (Shared Folders) on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, vmware, archlinux, vmware-tools

I'm using **VMware Workstation 10.0.1** and **Windows 7 32 bit**. I'm trying to install VMware Tools on Arch Linux to Share Folder between Windows host and Arch Linux guest.

Here is the details of my machine `uname -a`

```
Linux archlinux 3.18.2-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 9 07:23:08 CET 2015 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried to install **VMware tools** in various ways. Every time it installs successfully but only the **Shared Folder** feature didn't work. Neither the vmware supplied hgfs module nor the hgfs module from the open-vm-tools compiles on my machine.

I've tried both **Official VMware Tools** and **Open-VM-Tools** from [Installing Arch Linux in VMware](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_in_VMware). But no luck.

I've also tried the patch from GitHub [here](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches) to automate the process. But nothing changed.

I've also tried this patch got from another question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342703/vmware-shared-folders-hgfs-linux-kernel-3-12-ubuntu-14-04-not-compiling)

---

Here is in brief what I've done,

I've tried to install all the dependencies needed for Official VMware Tools and Open-VM-Tools. For this reason I've installed

```
# pacman -S base-devel net-tools linux-headers
```

and also installed `aurget` to install community packages. Then,

For installing Open-VM-Tools

```
# pacman -S open-vm-tools
$ aurget -S open-vm-tools-dkms // installed as regular user not root
# cat /proc/version > /etc/arch-release
# systemctl enable vmtoolsd.service
# reboot
```

For installing Official VMware Tools

```
# cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux
# ln -sv ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
# for x in {0..6}; do mkdir -pv /etc/init.d/rc$x.d; done
# mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
# cd /root
# tar zxf /mnt/VMwareTools*.tar.gz
# cd vmware-tools-distrib
# ./vmware-install.pl
# systemctl reboot
```

After rebooting and logging in,

```
# /etc/init.d/rc6.d/K99vmware-tools start
```

Then I've created a folder on my `D:\xshare` and added this to the machine by menu

```
VM --> Settings... --> Options --> Shared Folders
```

Then created a directory on the system

```
# mkdir /home/archuser/xshare
```

After that trying to share the folder between host and guest temporarily running this command

```
# mount -t vmhgfs .host:/xshare /home/archuser/xshare
Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

But getting error.

There is an instruction on the Arch installation page to solve this by running this but I'm also getting error here

```
# modprobe vmhgfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved applying a patch to the official VM tools. I was on a Mint (debian-based distro) box, so I don't know if you can use the same procedure on Arch, but I think that you can easily adapt it.

I followed the steps suggested [here](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/resolving-no-shared-folders-with-vmware-player-7-and-ubuntu-15-04-guest/comment-page-1), and in particular those indicated in Jorge's comment, that is:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
$ cd vmware-tools-patches
$ ./patched-open-vm-tools.sh
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I use VMware on a Windows 8 64Bit. The guest is Debian Wheezy.

```
# modprobe vmhgfs
FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found.
```

So the same here.

I suppose you set the shared folder in the configuration of the virtual machine:

Options --> Shared folders --> Add folders

I have set mine to German, so the names are only guessed.

Comment: Yes, I've set the shared folder as described before asking this question. And also got an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3140537). But didn't get the answer to do something.

Comment: Sorry, then I have no idea how to solve your problem. I can only suggest a workaround: If this is practical, you could make the folder publiy in Windows and mount it using SAMBA in your Arch guest.

Comment: It's ok. At least you've tried :)

Comment: I wanted to create a new line... Maybe the workaround with samba works for you?

Comment: I don't worked with SAMBA before, may be I'll try later if there is no hope. But I think there could be a way to solve this. I'm trying to find this.

Comment: Installed SAMBA. This is good to go for file sharing. But the VMware Tools should work.